# When fetching the HTML of a website, I can't seem to fetch the text of a <p> tag, only the <p> tag itself. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, request, python-requests

I've recently been experimenting with webscraping and using the python-requests module along with BeautifulSoup4.  However, in my newest project, I am trying to find the text of a certain `<p>` tag.  Here is a picture of the specific tag:
[image]

The site I am trying to scrape is https://www.adidas.com, and when I send a GET request to the site and print out the response's text, I get this:

`<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><title>YEEZY BOOST 350 V2 | adidas + KANYE WEST</title><script>window.PAGE_NAME = "yeezy-waitingroom";</script><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/wrgen_assets/favicon.ico"><link href="/wrgen_assets/906aa0ca31e9f5626ef5.css" rel="stylesheet"><script>bazadebezolkohpepadr="1471403990"</script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.adidas.com/akam/10/57b3d7fe" defer></script></head><body class="custom-c in-line yeezy yeezy-waitingroom"><header id="dw-header"></header><div class="kw in-line"><header class="top"><div class="inner"><figure class="logo"><a href="//www.adidas.com" target="_blank" data-url="home">adidas</a></figure><nav class="menu hidden"><ul class="menu-items"><li class="item men"><a href="#" data-url="men" data-lang="header_men_name"></a></li><li class="item women"><a href="#" data-url="women" data-lang="header_women_name"></a></li><li class="item kids"><a href="#" data-url="kids" data-lang="header_kids_name"></a></li><li class="item release-dates"><a href="#" manual_cm_sp="header-_-waiting room-_-release dates" data-url="release_dates" data-lang="header_release_dates_name"></a></li></ul></nav><aside class="ecom"><ul class="ecom-items"><li class="item my-account"><a href="#" data-url="my_account" alt="My Account"><span class="icon-user"></span></a></li><li class="item cart"><a href="#" data-url="cart" alt="Cart"><span class="icon-bag"></span></a></li></ul></aside></div></header><div id="content"><section class="section order-placed"><div class="inner order-placed"><h3 data-lang="order_placed_header"></h3><p data-lang="order_placed_description"></p><a href="#" class="btn get-updates" data-lang="product_get_updates_btn"></a></div></section><div class="actual-content"><section id="logo" class="section"><div class="inner"><h3 data-lang="waiting_room" data-auto-id="text-title"></h3><div class="status-message"><p class="uppercase" data-message-lang-key="statusMessageKey" data-auto-id="text-status-message"></p></div><p></p><div class="spinner"><div class="sk-fading-circle"><div class="sk-circle1 sk-circle"></div><div class="sk-circle2 sk-circle"></div><div class="sk-circle3 sk-circle"></div><div class="sk-circle4 sk-circle"></div><div class="sk-circle5 sk-circle"></div><div class="sk-circle6 sk-circle"></div><div class="sk-circle7 sk-circle"></div><div class="sk-circle8 sk-circle"></div><div class="sk-circle9 sk-circle"></div><div class="sk-circle10 sk-circle"></div><div class="sk-circle11 sk-circle"></div><div class="sk-circle12 sk-circle"></div></div></div><h1 class="wr11-mobile-name" data-product-info="productName"></h1><p class="wr11-mobile-price" data-product-info="priceFormatted"></p></div></section><section class="available-sizes"><div class="inner"><h1 class="uppercase" data-lang="available_sizes" data-auto-id="text-grid-message"></h1><ul></ul></div></section><section class="gallery-cart-wrapper"><div class="inner"><section id="gallery" class="section"><div class="inner owl-carousel owl-theme"></div></section><div class="wr11-right"><section id="intro" class="section"><div class="inner"><h1 class="name" data-product-info="productName" data-auto-id="text-product-name"></h1><p class="color" data-product-info="color" data-auto-id="text-product-color"></p><p class="price" data-product-info="priceFormatted" data-auto-id="text-product-price"></p><p class="no-discount uppercase" data-lang="product_no_discount" data-auto-id="text-discount"></p><p class="uppercase hidden" data-lang="product_return" data-auto-id="text-product-return"></p></div></section></div><div class="clearfix"></div></div></section></div></div><div class="feedback"><h3 data-lang="your_opinion"></h3><p data-lang="appreciate_your_feedback"></p><p id="qualtrics-feedback-footer"></p></div><footer class="bottom"><div class="inner"><ul class="links"><li class="link"><a href="#" data-url="sitemap" data-lang="footer_sitemap_name"></a></li><li class="link"><a href="#" data-url="cookies" data-lang="footer_cookies_name"></a></li><li class="link"><a href="#" data-url="privacy" data-lang="footer_privacy_name"></a></li><li class="link"><a href="#" data-url="terms" data-lang="footer_terms_name"></a></li><li class="link"><a href="#" data-url="imprint" data-lang="footer_imprint_name"></a></li></ul></div></footer><div id="consent_blackbar"></div></div><footer id="dw-footer"></footer><div id="getUpdatesModal" class="modal"><a href="#" class="close"><img src="/wrgen_assets/3229532920b3cb53141f41240544f78a.png" alt="close"></a><div class="inner"></div></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/wrgen_assets/906aa0ca31e9f5626ef5.js"></script><noscript><img src="https://www.adidas.com/akam/10/pixel_57b3d7fe?a=dD02Y2E4NDU1NmQwODM1MDcxYTk1ZjgwODdmNDYwNTFjZjg2YjViMzhiJmpzPW9mZg==" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -999px; top: -999px;" /></noscript></body></html>
<p class="uppercase" data-auto-id="text-status-message" data-message-lang-key="statusMessageKey"></p>`

I am able to find the tag in question with BS4 using `tag = soup.find('p', attrs={'class':'uppercase', 'data-message-lang-key':'statusMessageKey'})` but I could not find the content of the tag.  Eventually, I realized by doing a quick CTRL+F search of the python shell that the content of the tag was never even printed, which is why I had a hard time finding the text with BS4.

To get the HTML that I am scraping, I used:

```
s = requests.Session()
sitehtml = s.get('https://www.adidas.com/yeezy', headers=headers)
print(sitehtml.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(sitehtml.text, 'lxml')
```

Keep in mind I have defined the headers for the GET request earlier in my code.  What else can I use besides `sitehtml.text` to capture every part of the sites HTML, including the text of the `<p>` tag?

Comment: Have you thought of using Selenium with bs4?

Comment: The text is loaded into the page with Javascript in a second step (disable Javascript in your browser and reload the page to see what BS4 sees). It won't be possible to scrape this with BS4. Using selenium would be a way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you are trying to fetch is rendered through javascript. And the request get the html before any javascript do changes. so try to use splash or selenium or any other tool to first render the js and then parse response.